# Android: One Activity for all Fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

It is a good idea using only one `Activity` to loads the `Fragment` class passed as intent's extras? This solution works but i'm not sure it's a good pattern. I would like to use this approach beacuse (at the moment) each Fragment "is" an Activity, so I would prefer to avoid creating an Activity for each Fragment.

Here is an example of my Only Activity:

```
public class GenericActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.onepane);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        String fragmentToLoadName;
        try{
            fragmentToLoadName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("FRAGMENT");
        }catch(NullPointerException e){ 
            FragmentHelper.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment(), 
                    MainFragment.class.getName(), getSupportFragmentManager());

        }

        if(fragmentToLoadName!=null){
            Class fragment_to_load_class = null;
            try {
                fragmentToLoadClass = Class.forName(fragmentToLoadName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                FragmentHelper.add(R.id.fragment_container, (Fragment) fragmentToLoadClass.newInstance(), 
                        fragmentToLoadName, getSupportFragmentManager());
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The main disadvantage you will encounter is that if you want to setRetainInstance(true) on any of your Fragments, they will not be able to be added to the back stack. So you basically are giving up navigation via the device back button. This is definitely not a good way to do it.

Comment: I have made a test with setRetainInstance(true) for each fragment and navigation via back button works normally.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean) -- Please read the docs here. I'm inclined to believe that your judgment of normal is not accurate.

Comment: "This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated"